# Arduino IDE: "does not name a type", why can't I write this code?

Tags: c++, arduino

There are lots of explanations out there, but all of them are very code specific and complex.

Can someone tell my why this simple code won't compile?

```
int varOne, varTwo, varThree;

varOne = 1;
varTwo = 2;
varThree = 3;

void setup() {
// put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

I'm defining three variables at the beginning, and then I set values for each of them.
I will probably get lots of hate from posting this, but there was simply no clear explanation out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At file scope, i.e. outside any function, you may define variables (including their initialization) and other things, but you may not write arbitrary statements like assignments.

So you can write...

```
int varOne=1, varTwo=2, varThree=3;
```

which are definitions together with initializations, whereas

```
int varOne;
varOne = 1;
```

is a definition (legal) followed by an assignment, which is illegal at file scope.

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is what I needed. I guess some of these questions have to be asked when you teach yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change any varables outside the setup or run methods unless you are defining them at yhe same time. This is the arduino way of doing things which is only a problem because the background code is all hidden, otherwise, you could do the equivalent. I suggest either :

```
int var1 = 1, var2 = 2;
```

Or put it in setup:

```
int var1, var2;

void setup() {
    var1 = 1;
    var2 = 2;
}
```

Hope it helps!